# Keep images when adding choices to Google Forms with Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm using google scripts to add new choices to a checkbox item in a form every time the form gets submitted. Some of the existing checkbox-items have images attached that users see when filling in the form.

My problem is that every time my script gets run, it removes the images from the checkbox-items. Is there a way to keep the images attached to the form, while adding new choices to it?

(part of) my code:

```
  // retrieve form-checkbox object
  var item = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX)
    .filter(function(item){
      return item.getTitle() === 'Top 5 films';
    })[0].asCheckboxItem();
  
  //make 2 lists, 'choices' with all choices in the checkbox obj
  // 'existingChoicesTitles' with all the titles of the choices.
  var choices = item.getChoices();
  var existingChoicesTitles =  choices.map(function(value){
    return value.getValue();
  })

  //check if obj in list 'values' already exists in array 'choices, if not add to 
  //'choices'
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (existingChoicesTitles.includes(values[i]) == false){
      choices.push(item.createChoice(values[i]));
    }
  }
  //set 'choices' list as new list of choices
  item.setChoices(choices);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Unfortunately there is currently no way to do that.

There is an active Feature Request for the ability to add these kind of images with the Apps Script `FormApp`.

> #### [Add Images to Form Items](https://issuetracker.google.com/70078369)

I would suggest that you go and mark the ☆ on the issue to let Google know that you would like this functionality, and also to subscribe to updates. You might also want to add in your experience and use case in a comment.

---

In your case it seems that to add an item to the checkbox list, Apps Script regenerates all the checkbox items, and since `FormApp` doesn't support these types of images, it doesn't include them when they are regenerated.

For your use case there doesn't seem to be a practical workaround apart from simply *not* using images in this way if they are to be modified with Apps Script.

If you are willing to put in some extra work, you might want to implement the form as a simple [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). Then you would have almost infinite flexibility and far more functionality.

#### Web App example

This is a very simple example of a Web App that shows an input box and a button to send the info to the 'back-end', which in this example is `Code.gs`

#### `Code.gs`

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index")
}

function receiveInfo(formResponse) {
  Logger.log(formResponse)
}
```

#### `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <input type='text' id='input'></input>
    <button id=main>Send Info</button>

<script>   
function main(){
  const input = document.getElementById('input')
  const info = input.value
  google.script.run.receiveInfo(info)
}

const mainButton = document.getElementById("main")
mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => main())
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

#### References

- [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/70078369)
- [Web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Test a web app deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#test_a_web_app_deployment)
- [Client-to-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)